# How to add delegate value to tableview in swift

Tags: swift, delegates, tableview

Here I am sending secondVC textfield value to firstVC tableview but I am not receiving delegate value in tableview.

Here is my code:

In firstVC:

```
import UIKit

class CreateBusinessViewController: UIViewController, MyDataSendingDelegateProtocol, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var iteamsArray = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    func sendDataToFirstViewController(myData: String) {
        self.iteamsArray.append(myData)
        print(iteamsArray)
    }

     override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if (segue.identifier == "addSegue") {
            let vc = segue.destination as! CreatePopUpViewController
            vc.delegate = self
        }
     }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return iteamsArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! BusinessTableViewCell
        cell.nameLabel.text = iteamsArray[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }
}
```

In secondVC:

```
protocol MyDataSendingDelegateProtocol {
    func sendDataToFirstViewController(myData: String)
}

class CreatePopUpViewController: UIViewController {
    var delegate: MyDataSendingDelegateProtocol?

    @IBOutlet weak var addTf: UITextField!

    @IBAction func saveButn(_ sender: Any) {
        self.delegate?.sendDataToFirstViewController(myData: addTf.text!)

        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

How to add secondVC textfield data to firstVC array?

Comment: Where do you create and use an instance of `CreatePopUpViewController`? Show that code in your question.

Comment: i didn"t add where should i add please tell me i got stuck from long time @rmaddy

Comment: Somewhere you need to make use of your `CreatePopUpViewController` class. Obviously that code can't be run if you don't use it.

Comment: Please dont mind, i have updated code please check, still i am not recieving @rmaddy

Comment: Where do you show the `CreatePopUpViewController` instance that you store in `popupVC`? You can't expect the code to run if you don't show the view controller and if the user doesn't tap the save button.

Comment: Consider that `CreatePopUpViewController()` is **not** the instance in the storyboard. You need the **real** reference via segue or instantiation

Comment: please don't mind once check my code i have added segue, and now i got array values but i want to add array values to tableview cell label which i din"t get

Comment: you just need to reload the tableview after the data appended to the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Reflect the data to tableview cell you just need to reload the table view like i have updated your function check below code.

```
func sendDataToFirstViewController(myData: String) {
        self.iteamsArray.append(myData)
        tableView.reloadData()
        print(iteamsArray)
    }
```

Hope this way may help you.

Comment: thank you so much it works, you save my time... i accepted your answer but i can't upvote